# Why CMake does not propagate the PUBLIC include directories between libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, include-path

I have a C++ project with three shared libraries, let's call them `libA`, `libB` and `libC`. `libA` is dependant to both `libB` and `libC`. All of these three libraries are located inside a folder called `utilities`. Here is what I have:

Root `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20) # Required because of policy CMP0074

project(Test VERSION 2022)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{SHARED_PATH} SHARED_PATH)

add_subdirectory (utilities)
```

for `libB` I have the `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
add_library(libB SHARED
   inc/libB.h
   inc/libBExport.h
   src/libB.cpp
)

target_include_directories(libB
   PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
   PUBLIC ${SHARED_PATH}/inc
)

target_compile_definitions(libB
   PRIVATE LIBB_DLL)
```

and the same goes for `libC`:

```
add_library(libC SHARED
   inc/libC.h
   inc/libCExport.h
   src/libC.cpp
)

target_include_directories(libC
   PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
   PUBLIC ${SHARED_PATH}/inc
)

target_compile_definitions(libC
   PRIVATE LIBC_DLL)
```

Now, the `CMakeLists.txt` file for `libA` is like this:

```
add_library(libA SHARED
   inc/libA.h
   inc/libAExport.h
   src/libA.cpp
)

target_include_directories(libA
   PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
   PUBLIC ${SHARED_PATH}/inc
    )

target_link_directories(libA
   PUBLIC libB
   PUBLIC libC
)

target_compile_definitions(libA
   PRIVATE  LIBA_DLL)
```

Now, I generate the Visual Studio solution file using cmake:

```
> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
```

Everything goes fine. But when opening the solution with VS2019, `libB` and `libC` are compiling fine, but `libA` cannot be compiled with this error:

```
D:\code\proj\utilities\inc\libA.h(5,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libB.h': No such file or directory
D:\code\proj\utilities\inc\libA.h(9,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libC.h': No such file or directory
```

Can someone explain me why the the PUBLIC include directories of `libB` and `libC` are not inherited to `libA`?

Comment: `target_link_directories` for libA should be `target_link_libraries()`

Comment: don't use link_directories, instead you should link with the library itself using target_link_libraries: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: @drescherjm Oh, that was my mistake. You can write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the following:

```
target_link_directories(libA
   PUBLIC libB
   PUBLIC libC
)
```

You should use target_link_libraries().

```
target_link_libraries(libA
   PUBLIC libB
   PUBLIC libC
)
```

This will setup a dependency between the libraries which sets the include path, compiler settings, additional link directories, and additional link libraries.